# automatic transalation of django.po files using google translator

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I am having a very big django.po file with all msgids populated. Now i need to substitute msgstr with the equivalent translated string.Every time i need to copy the string to google translator get the translated string and paste it to the file.  Is there any too that can get the target language and populate all the msgstr's with the translated string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try django-rosetta app. It has automatic ajax-based bing translation as an option.

https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta

Comment: A few problems. 1) it doesn't really work with any translation services, (their Bing Translate support is broken and their Yandex support requires you to enter a Russian-language captcha), and 2) it doesn't do any bulk operations, you have to manually click "suggest" need to each entry to get a suggestion, not useful if you have hundreds of words to translate.

Answer (score 3):

It's late but it might help someone else :)

You can try the module [django-autotranslate](https://github.com/ankitpopli1891/django-autotranslate/).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, and I'd already started doing it manually, I searched and found django-autotranslate check it out here
https://pypi.org/project/django-autotranslate/
Its usage is explained in the same webpage.
It worked for me, and I believe it'll work for you.

Comment: This is the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28926615/5320906)